# Por que usar "git branch --unset-upstream"?

Tags: git

Criei um projeto e o deixei hospedado remotamente. Dai clono-o localmente, crio o remoto (remote), crio um arquivo teste.php e depois faço o add/commit/push.

Até aqui tudo bem. Agora faço um *branch* chamado teste, e já faço o add/commit/push.

E agora chegou o que eu queria perguntar: quando eu volto ao *branch* master, surge a mensagem:

> "Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
>     (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)"

Por que preciso executar esse `--unset-upstream`? O que significa esse comando? Fiz alguma coisa errada nas etapas anteriores? 
Depois os *branchs* acabam dando certo, porém não gosto de fazer as coisas por rumo. Por isso quero entender o que é esse `--unset-upstream` e por que ele me pede isso.

Comment: `crio o remoto (remote)` o que exatamente você faz nessa etapa? Quando você clona um projeto (git clone) ele já vem com o remote (origin) correto. Você está adicionando outro?

Comment: Ricardo, acredito que você matou a charada. Como comecei com o git recente, imaginava que sempre que fizesse um clone, eu já deveria criar um remote pra origem que clonei, sendo que na verdade esse remote já é criado por padrão. Dai repeti o processo usando o clone já padrão (origin) e o "erro" não aconteceu mais.  Obrigado.

Answer (score 5):

Você tem 2 opções:

1/ Faz um push para criar o ramo remoto, então criar a ligação que falta:

```
git push origin master
```

2/ Quebra a ligação local entre `master` e `origin/master`:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

A consequência disso é só que num `git fetch|pull|push`, vai ter que manualmente precisar os parâmetros ramo local y o ramo remoto para fazer a ligação. Além disso, `git status` não vai mostrar mais a divergência entre o ramo local y o remoto.

Para resumir, `--unset-upstream` só apaga uma ligação localmente, sem apagar nenhum dado. Pode depois e em qualquer momento refazer a ligação:

```
git branch master --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

**Generalmente**

Quando você cria um repository remoto (`git init --bare`), ele não tem nenhum ramo mas quando você clona o remoto num repository local, o ramo `master` tem uma ligação (upstream) com `origin/master`, mesmo se `origin/master` ainda não existe. Exemplo:

```
# Criação d'um repository remoto
$ mkdir remote.git && cd remote.git && git init --bare && cd ..
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/remote.git/

# Criação de um clone locale
$ git clone remote.git local && cd local
Cloning into 'local'...
warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
done.

# Criação do primeiro commit, necessario para ter um `git status` normal.
$ echo "txt" > file.txt && git add file.txt && git commit -m "Initial commit"

# A mensagem vá aparecer
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

# Verificando a ligacao `master` -> `origin/master`
$ git branch -vv
* master 8cbd8af [origin/master: gone] Initial commit
```

No seu caso, você fez outras modificações, tal vez erros. Primeiro, atualiza os dados do repository remoto:

```
git fetch origin
```

Verifica qual ramos remotos tem no repository remoto, e verifica as ligações:

```
git remote show origin
git branch -vv
```

Se você criou um mal ramo, pode apaga-o com (exemplo com ramo `test`):

```
git push origin :test
```